# Google Maps API V3 Infobox plugin hide/show?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API V3 plugin Infobox and I need some help. In the code a loop is creating several markers an infoboxes on the map, but I wonder how to hide the infoboxes from the beginning? I have tried to change the isHidden value, but not working. I also wonder how to hide previuosly infobox when click on a new marker to show a new infobox? Preciate some help! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="infobox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.672962361614566, 12.56587028503418);

    var myMapOptions = {
         zoom: 15
        ,center: latlng
        ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        ,streetViewControl: false
    };
    var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
// namn
var name=[];
name.push('Test 1');
name.push('Test 2');

// positioner
var position=[];
position.push(new google.maps.LatLng(55.667093265894245,12.581255435943604));
position.push(new google.maps.LatLng(55.66453963191134, 12.584795951843262));

// infoboxes
var infobox = [];
infobox.push("<div>Hello 1</div>");
infobox.push("<div>Hello 2</div>");

for (i = 0; i < position.length; i += 1) {
// Call function
createMarkers(position[i], infobox[i], name[i]);
}

function createMarkers(position,content,name) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: theMap,
        draggable: false,
        position: position,
        visible: true,
        title: name
    });

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "background: yellow; width: 300px; height: 70px; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = content;

    var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-37, -120)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
            background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
            ,opacity: 1
            ,width: "300px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "5px 5px 5px 5px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        ib.open(theMap, this);
    });

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    ib.open(theMap, marker);

    }

}
</script> 

<title>Creating and Using an InfoBox</title> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line:

```
ib.open(theMap, marker);
```

And the infobox should remain hidden until you click the marker.